# tsql return last price in each 10min time interval

Tags: t-sql, select, time, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express

I have a table comprising three columns: Date, Time, and Price.  The 'time' column is approximately minute intervals, but not every minute interval is represented.  I wish to create a new table comprising Date, FlooredTime, LastPriceInInterval, in which FlooredTime = the Time at the beginning of each 10min interval, and LastPriceInInterval is the price at the max available time within each interval.

```
Old Table:                          New Table:

Date    Time            Price       Date        FlooredTime LastPriceInInterval
2012-05-10  02:50:00    1352.7      2012-05-10  02:40:00    1353.0
2012-05-10  02:46:00    1353.0      2012-05-10  02:30:00    1353.5
2012-05-10  02:45:00    1352.8              
2012-05-10  02:44:00    1353.2              
2012-05-10  02:43:00    1353.1              
2012-05-10  02:42:00    1353.2              
2012-05-10  02:40:00    1353.4              
2012-05-10  02:39:00    1353.5              
2012-05-10  02:38:00    1354.6              
2012-05-11  03:31:00    1355.0              
2012-05-11  03:29:00    1354.0
```

This is what i have so far, but now i'm stuck.  It seems that the inner select statement doesn't like the use of Max in the where clause; Max(datepart(minute,m1.Time)%10).  Would greatly appreciate knowing how to achieve the desired outcome using permitted syntax.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 Date
   ,DATEADD(minute,-DATEPART(minute,Time)%10 ,Time) as FlooredTime
   ,(Select Price from dbo.MyData
         where m3.Date = m1.Date
         and DATEPART(hour, m3.Time) = DATEPART(hour, m1.Time)
         and datepart(minute,m3.Time)/10 = Floor(datepart(minute,m1.Time)/10)
         and datepart(minute,m3.Time)%10 = Max(datepart(minute,m1.Time)%10)
         ) as LastPriceInInterval
FROM dbo.MyData
where DATEPART(minute,Time)%10 = 0
order by Date Desc, Time Desc
```

Thanks!

A late edit - I'll later use the results as the source table in a Merge expression.

Comment: `tsql` tells us it's SQL Server or Sybase, but *which one* are you using, and *what version*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you identify the intervals first, get the maximum time for each interval, then join with the table to get the price? Using a `CTE` you could easily achieve this:

```
;WITH intervals(Date, T1, MaxTime) AS (
SELECT
    Date
    , DATEADD(minute, -DATEPART(minute, Time)%10, Time)
    , MAX(Time) AS MaxTime
FROM dbo.MyData
GROUP BY Date
    , DATEADD(minute, -DATEPART(minute, Time)%10, Time)
)
SELECT t.Date AS Date, i.T1 AS Time, t.Price
FROM dbo.MyData t
INNER JOIN intervals i ON t.Date = i.Date AND t.Time = i.MaxTime
ORDER BY Date DESC, Time DESC
```

Comment: Good point, `T2` is the end of the interval. I tried using a `BETWEEN` statement, and forgot to take it out. I have updated my answer and upvoted your comment.

Comment: Thank you!  This does indeed return the required data and is a beneficial learning experience to see how you approached it. What i didn't mention in the original question is that i will use the returned table as the source table in a merge statement.  If i understand correctly i can't use CTE for this

Comment: @user1225208 - There's no obstacle to using a CTE as the source of a `MERGE`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like my wrapping the above solution in a Using statement.  eg. Merge xyz as target Using ( ;With Intervals... ) as Source ON ... 
Tried dropping semicolon but that didn't help either.

Comment: All fine now.  Worked out what i was doing wrong.  

Thank you all for your helpful suggestions.  I learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could rank rows in the reversed order of `Time` within their respective 10-minute intervals, then pick the top-ranked ones:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    FlooredTime = DATEADD(MINUTE, -DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, Time) % 10, Time),
    TimeRank    = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, Time) / 10
      ORDER BY Time DESC
    )
  FROM MyData
)
SELECT
  Date,
  FlooredTime,
  LastPriceInInterval = Price
FROM ranked
WHERE TimeRank = 1
ORDER BY
  Date DESC,
  FlooredTime DESC
;
```

[Here's a SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46678/1) for the query.

Comment: That is an interesting way to approach it.  I'm not sure why however, but when i run it on my larger data set, i only get 144 row results (not sure how it relates to your code logic, but 144 * 10min = 1 day).

Comment: If your larger data set represents an entire single day and all 10-minute intervals are represented in that data set by at least one row each, then 144 rows is certainly what I would expect as a result of this query. Or what am I missing?